# Get anchor tag to open in new window

Tags: html, tags, anchor

Is there a way to get anchor tags to open in a new window instead of the current one?

```
    <a href="my_link">Link</a>
```

Answer (score -18, accepted):

Use jQuery/javascript to open in new window

```
$('a').click(function(){ 
  window.open('http://google.com') 
});
```

Answer (score 40):

Set the [`target`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-target) attribute to `_blank`.

You have no control over what sort of new "window" the browser will open it in. It might be an actual window, it might be a tab, it might be overridden and forced to the same window.

It is, however, [a bad idea](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-mistakes-web-design/), so [don't do it](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/07/01/should-links-open-in-new-windows/), really, [please don't](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19892/opening-website-external-links-in-new-window-published-usability-tests).

Comment: Thank you for the noting this is a bad idea.  The references were really helpful and clear.  I will definitely avoid forcing links to open in new windows from now on.

Answer (score 6):

you no need to write such long javascript to do with your requirement. Just set target attribute to _blank in your anchir tag itself. whenever a user click on that link it will open in new tab. sample tag is as follow

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Hope this helps you

**NOTE:  [For Security reason](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/)**

Comment: target="_blank" is not working for me.
Its throwing error, but target="new" is working fine.

Comment: oh, I'm not sure why _blank is not working. but, it's working for me still. may browser support or something like that.

Comment: `new` is working for me as well in Chrome browser.

Answer (score 4):

This will work  but its pure javascript

```
<a href="http://www.snopzer.com" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'Snopzer',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" >Open Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to do:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="new">Google</a>
```

This will open whatever the link given in a new tab.

Comment: how to open in new window tough?